# Error in using lapply?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I want to divide each column of my dataframe "data" by each column of another dataframe called "benchmark". However, I get different results using lapply and dividing it manually. Where is the error in my code?

The code I use is:

```
div <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) x[col(benchmark)]/benchmark))
```

For the first two columns, this gives me the following result...

```
   div.A.B1  div.A.B2
1  0.7200000 0.8000000
2  0.7422680 0.8163265
3  0.7346939 0.8080808
4  0.7422680 0.8333333
5  0.7578947 0.8510638
6  0.7741935 0.8695652
7  0.7826087 0.8510638
8  0.7826087 0.8602151
9  0.7912088 0.8791209
10 0.8181818 0.8791209
```

... while dividing the first column of "data" by the first two columns of "benchmark" manually gives me:

```
        A.B1      A.B2
1  0.7200000 0.7200000
2  0.8247423 0.8163265
3  0.7653061 0.7575758
4  0.7525773 0.7604167
5  0.9473684 0.9574468
6  0.8709677 0.8804348
7  0.8804348 0.8617021
8  0.9347826 0.9247312
9  1.0989011 1.0989011
10 0.9090909 0.8791209
```

Some sample data for "data":

```
     A
1   72
2   80
3   75
4   73
5   90
6   81
7   81
8   86
9  100
10  80
```

and for "benchmark":

```
    B1  B2
1  100 100
2   97  98
3   98  99
4   97  96
5   95  94
6   93  92
7   92  94
8   92  93
9   91  91
10  88  91
```

Comment: How about `df1/df2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to try purrr for this one, it has some functions which let you map across multiple lists which is helpful for this case. In this case you could use something like 
`map2_df(data, benchmark, ~.x / .y)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outer`:

```
data <- read.table(text = "     A1 A2 
                   1   72 11
                   2   80 20
                   3   75 15
                   4   73 17
                   5   90 13
                   6   81 18
                   7   81 22
                   8   86 30
                   9  100 20
                   10  80 22", header = TRUE)

benchmark <- read.table(text = "    B1  B2
1  100 100
                        2   97  98
                        3   98  99
                        4   97  96
                        5   95  94
                        6   93  92
                        7   92  94
                        8   92  93
                        9   91  91
                        10  88  91", header = TRUE)

res <- outer(seq_along(data), seq_along(benchmark), 
      function(i, j, DF1, DF2) DF1[,i] / DF2[, j], 
      DF1 = data, DF2 = benchmark)

names(res) <- outer(names(data), names(benchmark), paste, sep = ".")
#       A1.B1     A2.B1     A1.B2     A2.B2
#1  0.7200000 0.1100000 0.7200000 0.1100000
#2  0.8247423 0.2061856 0.8163265 0.2040816
#3  0.7653061 0.1530612 0.7575758 0.1515152
#4  0.7525773 0.1752577 0.7604167 0.1770833
#5  0.9473684 0.1368421 0.9574468 0.1382979
#6  0.8709677 0.1935484 0.8804348 0.1956522
#7  0.8804348 0.2391304 0.8617021 0.2340426
#8  0.9347826 0.3260870 0.9247312 0.3225806
#9  1.0989011 0.2197802 1.0989011 0.2197802
#10 0.9090909 0.2500000 0.8791209 0.2417582
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `df1/df2`, see example:

```
#dummy data
df1 <- mtcars[1:5, 1, drop = FALSE]
df2 <- mtcars[1:5, 4:6]

df1; df2

#                   mpg
# Mazda RX4         21.0
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0
# Datsun 710        22.8
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7

#                    hp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4         110 3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag     110 3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710         93 3.85 2.320
# Hornet 4 Drive    110 3.08 3.215
# Hornet Sportabout 175 3.15 3.440


df1$mpg/df2
#                          hp     drat       wt
# Mazda RX4         0.1909091 5.384615 8.015267
# Mazda RX4 Wag     0.1909091 5.384615 7.304348
# Datsun 710        0.2451613 5.922078 9.827586
# Hornet 4 Drive    0.1945455 6.948052 6.656299
# Hornet Sportabout 0.1068571 5.936508 5.436047
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
A=data; B=benchmark
matrix(apply(A, 2, function(x, y) apply(y, 2, function(z, x) x/z, x), B), nrow(A), ncol(A)*ncol(B), byrow = F)
          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 0.7200000 0.7200000
 [2,] 0.8247423 0.8163265
 [3,] 0.7653061 0.7575758
 [4,] 0.7525773 0.7604167
 [5,] 0.9473684 0.9574468
 [6,] 0.8709677 0.8804348
 [7,] 0.8804348 0.8617021
 [8,] 0.9347826 0.9247312
 [9,] 1.0989011 1.0989011
[10,] 0.9090909 0.8791209
```

The idea behind are two nested apply functions. The result is transformed appropriate using the `matrix()` function.
Or with Rolands data. Please take care that the ordering is `A1B1, A1B2, A2B1, A2B2`

```
matrix(apply(data, 2, function(x,y) apply(y, 2, function(z,x) x/z, x), benchmark), nrow(data) , ncol(data)*ncol(benchmark), byrow = F)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
 [1,] 0.7200000 0.7200000 0.1100000 0.1100000
 [2,] 0.8247423 0.8163265 0.2061856 0.2040816
 [3,] 0.7653061 0.7575758 0.1530612 0.1515152
 [4,] 0.7525773 0.7604167 0.1752577 0.1770833
 [5,] 0.9473684 0.9574468 0.1368421 0.1382979
 [6,] 0.8709677 0.8804348 0.1935484 0.1956522
 [7,] 0.8804348 0.8617021 0.2391304 0.2340426
 [8,] 0.9347826 0.9247312 0.3260870 0.3225806
 [9,] 1.0989011 1.0989011 0.2197802 0.2197802
[10,] 0.9090909 0.8791209 0.2500000 0.2417582
```

Or combining the answer of zx8754 gives you a list of the divisions which can be binded together with `do.call`:

```
do.call("cbind", apply(data, 2, function(x,y) x/y, benchmark))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `expand.grid`:

```
e <- do.call(expand.grid, list(1:ncol(data),1:ncol(benchmark)))

# e will give you all possible permutations of columns on which you can apply division
  # Var1 Var2
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    1
# 3    1    2
# 4    2    2

r <- apply(e, 1, function(x) data[,x[1]]/benchmark[,x[2]])

# to make descriptive column names for r
colnames(r) <- apply(expand.grid(names(data), names(benchmark)), 1, paste, collapse="/")

         # A1/B1     A2/B1     A1/B2     A2/B2
 # [1,] 0.7200000 0.1100000 0.7200000 0.1100000
 # [2,] 0.8247423 0.2061856 0.8163265 0.2040816
 # [3,] 0.7653061 0.1530612 0.7575758 0.1515152
 # [4,] 0.7525773 0.1752577 0.7604167 0.1770833
 # [5,] 0.9473684 0.1368421 0.9574468 0.1382979
 # [6,] 0.8709677 0.1935484 0.8804348 0.1956522
 # [7,] 0.8804348 0.2391304 0.8617021 0.2340426
 # [8,] 0.9347826 0.3260870 0.9247312 0.3225806
 # [9,] 1.0989011 0.2197802 1.0989011 0.2197802
# [10,] 0.9090909 0.2500000 0.8791209 0.2417582
```

**DATA**

```
data <- structure(list(A1 = c(72L, 80L, 75L, 73L, 90L, 81L, 81L, 86L, 
100L, 80L), A2 = c(11L, 20L, 15L, 17L, 13L, 18L, 22L, 30L, 20L, 
22L)), .Names = c("A1", "A2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

benchmark <- structure(list(B1 = c(100L, 97L, 98L, 97L, 95L, 93L, 92L, 92L, 
91L, 88L), B2 = c(100L, 98L, 99L, 96L, 94L, 92L, 94L, 93L, 91L, 
91L)), .Names = c("B1", "B2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```